# Is it possible to select columns from table, update it and copy updated data to another table with postgres DB?

Tags: postgresql

I want to select data from the table to modify that data without a change in the original table and copy that modified data to another table.

for example, I have table name student

student

```
id | name |isPresent
1  | xyz  | 1
2  | lmn  | 1
```

and I want to show copy data like

```
id | name |isPresent
1  | xyz  | 0
2  | lmn  | 0
```

how could I do this with the help of a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`:

```sql
INSERT INTO copyTable (id, name, isPresent)
SELECT id, name, 0
FROM yourTable;
```

This assumes that you want to copy all data in your original table (`yourTable`) into a new table (`copyTable`), with the requirement that all `isPresent` values be set to zero for that original data in the new table.